# How to evaluate javascript variable inside jQuery append?

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

I have an array of objects (`array`), each with a property containing a URL string that routes to an image. I am trying to use jQuery to loop through this array and append each object's image into a `div`. Here is my code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    $('#div').append("<img src=\"array[i].URL\" alt=\"pic\">");
}
```

Note: I used the backslashes to escape the quotes in the img tag.

The javascript is not evaluating inside the `append` method and it is simply printing "array[i].URL" for the image address on the page.

Can someone give me a heads-up on what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: `'<img src="' + array[i].URL + '" alt="pic">'`  @somethinghere thx, for the detailed explanation.

Comment: To clarify @fuyushimoya - You need to concatenate using `+` in javascript, and you can intermingle `'` and `"` to create quotes. Javascript does not have a built-in way of evaluating strings to their context, so you will have to manually concatenate.

Comment: nothing to do with jquery. this is a basic javascript problem...

Comment: Just to clarify @somethinghere's comment: JavaScript *didn't* have a way of evaluating this sort of thing until ES2015. Now it does, and [support is even half-decent](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-template_strings) though you couldn't rely on it (without transpiling) in the wild just yet. :-)

Comment: To clarify @T.J.Crowder answer: Cool! He has it in his answer :) But as he said, don't start using it in production just yet and stick to concatenating until this is universally supported!

Comment: @somethinghere: Or transpile. :-) I'm **loving** [Babel](http://babeljs.io) (no affiliation).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Bookmarked! (I had not seen this one yet - I had seen Google's Tracuer (was it named traceur?) But that was so slow. Will be playing with this tomorrow!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a bunch of options:

1. [`$()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-html-ownerDocument) and [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr):

   ```
   for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
       $('#div').append(
           $('<img alt="pic">').attr("src", array[i].URL)
       );
   }
   ```
2. String concatenation:

   ```
   for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
       $('#div').append(
           '<img src="' + array[i].URL + '" alt="pic">'
       );
   }
   ```
3. In ES2015+, you have [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings):

   ```
   for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
       $('#div').append(
           `<img src="${array[i].URL}" alt="pic">`
       );
   }
   ```

   Note the `${` and the `}` — the bit in-between them is evaluated by the JavaScript engine and swapped in a that point. Also note that they're quoted with backticks, not single or double quotes.

Comment: Oe neat, I didn't know about template strings in ES2015 yet.

Comment: Shouldn't `\`<img src="${array[i].URL}" alt="pic">'` be `\`<img src="${array[i].URL}" alt="pic">\``

Comment: @MatteoTassinari: You talking about the `'` instead of backtick at the end? Yeah, noticed that, thanks. Fixed now. :-)